# I've done a program to display student name and height using queue linked list in C++ now i want to display it in Desceding order i dont know how

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

```
using namespace std;

void createsqueue();
void insertname();
void insertheight();
void del();
void push();
void display();

struct nodename
{
  string name;
  float height;
  struct nodename *next;

};
nodename *front;
nodename *rear;

void createstack()
{
   front = NULL;
   rear = NULL;
}
void insertname()
{
while (true)
{
  char dec;
  nodename *temp;
  temp = new nodename;
  std::cout << "ENTER YOUR NAME : ";
  std::cin >> temp -> name;
  std::cout << "ENTER YOUR HEIGHT : ";
  std::cin >> temp -> height;
  std::cout <<'\n';
  temp -> next = NULL;
if(rear == NULL)
{
   rear = temp;
   front = temp;
}
else
{
   rear -> next = temp;
   rear = temp;
}
 std::cout << "ADD ANOTHER DATA? (Y/N) : ";
 std::cin >> dec;
 std::cout <<'\n';
 if (dec == 'n' || dec == 'N')
{
break;
  }
 }

}

void del()
{
if(front != NULL)
 {
    nodename *temp = front;
    cout << "The deleted element is: " << temp -> name << endl;
    front = front -> next;
    delete temp;
 }
 else
  {
    cout << "Queue List is empty!\n";
  }

 }

  void display()
  {
    nodename *temp = front;
    while(temp != NULL)
     {
        std::cout << "--------------------------" << '\n';
        std::cout <<"NAME : "<< temp -> name << endl;
        std::cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(0);
        std::cout <<"HEIGHT : " << temp -> height << endl;
        std::cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2);
        temp = temp -> next;
        std::cout << "--------------------------" << '\n';

     }
    }

    int main()
    {
      int operation;
      createstack();
      do
        {
          std::cout << "\tMAIN MENU" << endl;
          std::cout << "1 - ENTER NAME : "
          << "\n2 - DELETE PREV DATA : "
          << "\n3 - DISPLAY DATA : "
          << "\n0 - End Program"
          << "\nEnter your operation: ";
          cin >> operation;
          switch (operation)
           {
             case 1: insertname();
             break;
             case 2: del();
             break;
             case 3: display();
             break;
             case 0: cout << "Program End";
             break;
             default:
             cout << "Wrong option. Please insert a new operation: ";
           }
          }
         while(operation ! = 0);
         return 0;
         }
```

This is the code.
The program Works fine the only problem I have is displaying the name with height in descending order so that the tallest person's info displays first
I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work it might be my in-experience in coding since im a newbie and pardon me for any error im just getting started

Comment: Two ways: Either insert nodes in the list sorted in the correct order; Or sort the list once all nodes have been added. Then it's just a matter of iterating over the list in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code for inserting a new name such that whenever you add a node,you find the correct position for it before inserting in the linked list.

```
void insertname(){
cin>>h;
nodename* ctr=front;
while(ctr-> height >h){
ctr=ctr->next;
}
nodename* temp =new nodename;
temp->next=ctr->next
ctr->next=temp
temp->height=h; //similarly for name

}
```

Just find it if the node added is the first node or any other which you have achieved and the above will add nodes in the descending order, which will be displayed as you wanted. So, you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: What happens if you run of the end of the list before finding the node? You need to take care to check `ctr` first.